# cannot get id of li on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to show tabs.

```
  $start = strtotime($_GET['date']);
   $dates = array();
   for ($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++) {

    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$i day", $start));
    $date1 = $date;
    $day = date('D', strtotime($date1));
    $date = explode('-', $date);
    $dateinput = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$i day", $start));
    $date = $date[2];
    echo '<li class="lia" id="'.$dateinput.'"><input type="hidden"    class="getdate" value="'.$dateinput.'"><a href="#tabs-'.$i.'" class="date">' .    $date . '  ' . $day . '</a></li>';

    }
```

I have a date-picker and i want to get the id of li by on change function of datepicker. I am using this code at moment.

```
 $("#calendar-<?php echo $post->ID?>").on("change",function(){
    var date = $(this).val();
    console.log(date);
    var libtn= $("li.lia").find("li").attr("id");
    console.log(libtn);
    alert(libtn);
  });
```

It is showing undefined in alert box. Where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Replace    var libtn= $("li.lia").find("li").attr("id"); line by var libtn = $("li.lia").attr("id");

Comment: which datepicker you are using?

Comment: jquery datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
var libtn= $("li.lia").find("li").attr("id");
```

With

```
var libtn = $("li.lia").attr("id");
```

And check.

You can not find element itself inside same element.

**EDIT**

I am expecting you will have `lia` class everywhere means on every li.

Then, 
Here is the code,

```
$("li.lia").each(function(i,j){
 console.log($(this).attr("id")); // use as per your requirement
});
```

Comment: thanks but this is only giving me first one. i need ids of all li's. Let me edit my question a little bit.

Comment: Welcome ! If it solves your problem, please accept my answer.